# How can I correctly deploy static and compiled assets in rails with nginx and capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline, rvm-capistrano

In my project, I have tried to bundle most of my js libraries into gems so they can be updated and pulled in whenever necessary, however, I've recently setup our production server and I'm having issues with asset compilation and static assets in /public/assets.

Specifically, when I don't use the asset pipeline, I have no issues with datatables or any other JS libraries or css that I am trying to use. I am precompiling my assets in production and using a typical nginx setup (based on railscast #335) to serve them.

Static assets are the following -

public/assets

```
javascript/jquery.formatCurrency-1.4.0.min.js
stylesheets/datepicker.css
twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-datepicker.js
```

is public/assets the correct place for these?

When I deploy with capistrano, these assets get a 404 when loading the page and are not actually copied to the /public/assets directory on the server.

When loading other pages I am calling the datatables plugin as follows

```
$('#inventory_item_list_datatable').dataTable
  sDom: "<'row'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
  sPaginationType: "bootstrap",
  iDisplayLength: 100
```

Datatables is compiled into my application.js and doesn't throw an error, but the table never actually renders. I'm wondering if this is related to the order that everything is compiled?

app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery_nested_form
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
<link href="/assets/stylesheets/datepicker.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

---edit datatables issue

when using jquery-datatables-rails gem it must be OUTSIDE of your assets group in gemfile.

Comment: When you say that you are precompiling the assets, are you doing that locally? If so, do you have a capistrano task that actually syncs these files to your production server? Are they a part of your repository? If you go to the `public/assets` directory on your server, is there anything in there?

Comment: I am using capistrano to precompile the assets on the server.      load 'deploy/assets'
All of the styling and everything else is there EXCEPT the files I have locally in my public/assets directory.

Comment: So the assets you describe at the top (formatCurrency, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker) are in your `public/assets` directory and not being loaded through the pipeline? If that's the case, I'm assuming you are ignoring the `public/assets` from your repository. You should probably stick those in `vendor/assets`, load them through the pipeline, and then they should be thrown into `public/assets` when precompile happens.

Comment: my repo does not ignore /public/assets. Is vendor/assets the accepted place for these? what would the local public/assets directory be used for?

Comment: Yes. If you are including assets, such as css/js/images, that "are not yours" (if you know what I mean), then yes, `vendor/assets` is the accepted place for these.

Comment: I have moved everything into vendor/assets, but the files are not copied there by capistrano.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24147/discussion-between-theiv-and-kosmonaut)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default , asset-pipeline comes with 3 locations for placing the assets : `app/assets`, `lib/assets` and `vendor/assets` . You have to place (in case you'd like to rely on the pipeline) your assets there , not in the `public/` . In the production env all the assets are compressed and transformed into one file (respectively for `.js` and `.css` ) : `application.*` .

EDIT : In this case the `assets` directory was structured differently . After the chat with @theIV and @Kosmonaut , we have found the solution : moving the assets to the `vendor/assets` directory with structure :

For Javascript assets:

```
 vendor/assets/javascripts/specific_javasripts
```

and for CSS:

```
vendor/assets/stylesheets/specific_stylesheets
```

By default , the `vendor/assets/` directory does not contain `javascripts` nor `stylesheets` directories , they should be created .